# How to add random effects in a tree taper model?

Tags: mixed-models, non-linear-regression, rscript, random-effects

I am learning to fit a tree taper mixed model using R. So I would like to know how can I add random effects in the model?

Let's say we fit the model using variable-exponent taper funtion of Kozak (2004).

This is the formula:

diameter ~ b0*(dbh^b1)*(hight^b2)*((1-hih^(1/3))/(1-(p^(1/3))))^x

```
       x = (b3*hih^4+b4*(1/exp(dbh/hight))+b5*((1-hih^(1/3))/(1-(p^(1/3))))^0.1
           +b6*(1/dbh)+b7*(h^(1-hih^(1/3)))+b8*((1-hih^(1/3))/(1-(p^(1/3)))))
```

So, please, let me know the R script.

Answer (score 0):

I've used taper equations quite extensively, and I would just reiterate that it's important to make sure that you have implemented and defined your equation properly in R before constructing your models. That being said:

You can assign random parameters within the function **nlme()** in R.

Here's an example with some fictitious taper model named 'taper' that has 3 model parameters (a1,a2,a3), and the predictors DBH, H, and L (where 'DBH' is diameter at breast height, 'H' is tree height, and 'L' is the height along stem where the diameter measurement is taken:

```
nlme(D ~ (Taper(DBH,H,L,a1,a2,a3)),
     data = Your Data,
     fixed = a1, a2, a3,
     random = a1 + a2 ~1|Your Grouping Variable,
     start = c( a1 = 0.001, a2 = 0.001, a3 = 0.001))
```

This code won't run -- as it's just an example. But you assign your random parameters in:

**random = ()**

Read up on nlme() in R for proper syntax and components for proper fitting. Goodluck!